# Difference between emulator and my device

Tags: android

i am put margin top and button 90dp in xml but it show in emulator https://www.dropbox.com/s/1lnrtn7512cyiwz/device-2014-02-05-112601.jpg and show in my device(galaxy fit) https://www.dropbox.com/s/40zzq7liov9n4zh/SC20140127-114334.png 
what???
this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backpunzdahta" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="90dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid1" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid2" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid3" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid4" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid5" />
                    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid6" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid7" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid8" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid9" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid10" />
                    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid11" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid12" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid13" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid14" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton15"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/buttonjadid15" />

    </LinearLayout>
 </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be having problem with your settings. That is your emulator is set to some other version which do not match with your device. This is the main problem you can have with `User Interface` issues.